# function's return type's need

Tags: c++

//we all always specify the return type of a function because it is in the syntax.....but can anyone tell me what basic objective is served by us by specifying the function's return type..........means why did the syntax have to be made like this.....it could be that we could just return the value..

Comment: It used to be that functions were assumed to return `int` if you didn't specify otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to specify the type in a function declaration because not all function declarations are definitions.  For example, consider the following declaration that we could have if a return type wasn't required:

```
f(int x);
```

What is the type of `f(42)`?  There's no way to know from this declaration, hence the return type is required to be specified.

Or, consider the following function with a definition (assume `C` is some class):

```
g(bool b) {
    if (b) {
        return C();
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```

What should the return type of `g` be?  It could be `double` or it could be `C`.

The syntax "has to be like this" because C++ is built on C, which has practically no type inference.  C++ could have been built on some other language, in which case this wouldn't "have to be made like this," but then C++ would be a completely different language.

Note that C++0x adds one place where a function return type *can* be deduced:  if a lambda expression body consists of a single `return` statement, then the return type of the lambda is deduced to be the type of the expression from the `return` statement (if the lambda is of any other form, the return type is deduced to be `void` unless a return type is explicitly specified).  So, the following are identical:

```
[]() -> int { return 42; }
[]() { return 42; }
```

Lambda expressions are special, though, since you can't declare a lambda without defining it.

Comment: So why not extend the possibility for the compiler to deduce the return type of functions consisting of a single return statement, as with lambda? it would help a lot in some cases. May it happen in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly from the same reason you specify the types of the arguments the function receives.

Also, assuming that you don't specify the return value --

```
function f( int x ) { if (x == 0) return x; else return (x == 0); }
```

What would *f* return?

Answer (score 1):

C++ was designed as a [strongly typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Strong_and_weak_typing) language, specifying the type of the return value allows the compiler to verify that what a caller expects as type is returned by a called function. This a.o. allows to detect logic errors in the program at compile time, rather than at runtime. Weakly typed programming languages (e.g. perl) do not require you to specify return type. Each has its own advantages/disadvantages on which you can find plenty information on the internet.

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with "strong" vs. "weak" typing, it has to do with the possibility for type inference.  You can have a "strongly" typed language where most of the types are inferred (e.g., F#).  The problem is that in C++ it is difficult or impossible to infer types in many cases because the language has so many ways to convert between different types (explicit casts, implicit conversions, conversion functions, converting constructors, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If there is no return type, then we cannot write the last line of this snippet:

```
f(int a)
{
   if ( a == 0 ) return 100;
   else          return "a is not zero";
}

//ambiguous return type
int a = f(b); // b is known at runtime!
```

Since `b` is known at runtime, we cannot decide whether the function `f` will return `100` or the string `a is not zero`; if we cannot decide the return value, then we cannot decide (and write) the type of return value at calling site, that means we cannot write `int a = f(b)` because it could be `const char* c = f(b)` as well.

For a dynamically-typed language, it is possible. But C++ is not that, C++ is a statically-typed language. That means, every *type* should be known at compile time!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few reasons:

1. **C++ was "built on" C, and that's the way it was in C.**
2. **You can declare a function without defining it.**
3. **It lets the compiler catch errors for you.**